# php: for each record in one mysql table, display all the records from a 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one with email addresses, and one with a number of rows per email address:

```
Table 1:
1@gmail.com
2@gmail.com
etc

Table 2:
1@gmail.com,value111,value112,value113
1@gmail.com,value121,value122,value123
2@gmail.com,value211,value212,value213
etc.
```

I want to send each of the email addresses their values, so I get the email:

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM email_table";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$email = $row['email'];
```

and then, I need to get the values for each email.
I tried using foreach but apparently not in a correct way
Can anybody help?

Many thanks!

Comment: Read up on how to use SQL joins.  This is what you want to do.

Comment: You don't need to query Table 1 for this, since all the data is in Table 2

Comment: Since you have the email addresses in the 2nd table, is there a reason you need to select the 1st table?

Comment: I think `GROUP BY email` with `GROUP_CONCAT` from second table helps you

Comment: And use mysqli or PDO functions PHP will drop mysql_ function support in the future

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: 2 tables are needed because not all the adresses in table2 should get a mail. But my question is not about joining tables, it is about sending emails: how do I send the values from table 2 to the email adresses in table1. Meaning 1@gmail.com gets values value111,value112,value113 value121,value122,value123, 2@gmail.com gets values value211,value212,value213 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM email_table AS table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.email = table1.email";
```

**--edit--** 
after clarification, you want to get the info from table 2 attached to the email address in table 1 and send an email to table 1...

```
$query = "SELECT table1.email, table2.* FROM email_table AS table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.email = table1.email";
```

Your result here is the email field from table 1 with all information from table 2 joined on the same email address. You don't need both emails returned here so in your field list, put something like this instead of `table2.*`:

```
SELECT table1.email, table2.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3
```

Then you can use PHP's `mail` to send to the email you get from table1.

Comment: Why JOIN anything? Table 2 has all the data.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your efforts, but this will have the effect that 1@gmail.com gets two emails, one with the values value111,value112,value113 and a second one with the values value121,value122,value123. But I want 1@gmail.com to receive just one email, with all 6 values.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to do a `JOIN`. So your query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON (table2.email = table1.email);
```

[Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) has a great explanation of all the join types between the tables.

Comment: Why `JOIN` anything? Table 2 has all the data.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: 2 tables are needed because not all the adresses in table2 should get a mail. But my question is not about joining tables, it is about sending emails: how do I send the values from table 2 to the email adresses in table1.

Comment: Meaning 1@gmail.com gets values value111,value112,value113
value121,value122,value123, 2@gmail.com gets values value211,value212,value213 etc.